# PHP LDAP - Display group parent of a Group

Tags: php, search, ldap

I have a script as below, from (https://samjlevy.com/archives/) that displays the memberOf attribute

```
<?php
function get_groups($user) {
// Active Directory server
  $ldap_server = "****************";

// Active Directory DN, base path for our querying user

$ldap_dn = "dc=registry,dc=otago,dc=ac,dc=nz";
// Active Directory user for querying
$query_user = "*************";
$password = "************";

// Connect to AD
$ldap = ldap_connect($ldap_server) or die("Could not connect to LDAP");
ldap_bind($ldap,$query_user,$password) or die("Could not bind to LDAP");

// Search AD
$results = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,"(samaccountname=$user)",array("memberof","primarygroupid"));
$entries = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results);

// No information found, bad user
if($entries['count'] == 0) return false;

// Get groups and primary group token
$output = $entries[0]['memberof'];
$token = $entries[0]['primarygroupid'][0];

// Remove extraneous first entry
array_shift($output);

// We need to look up the primary group, get list of all groups
$results2 = ldap_search($ldap,$ldap_dn,"(objectcategory=group)",array("distinguishedname","primarygrouptoken"));
$entries2 = ldap_get_entries($ldap, $results2);

// Remove extraneous first entry
array_shift($entries2);

// Loop through and find group with a matching primary group token
foreach($entries2 as $e) {
    if($e['primarygrouptoken'][0] == $token) {
        // Primary group found, add it to output array
        $output[] = $e['distinguishedname'][0];
        // Break loop
        break;
    }
}

return $output;
}

// Example Usage
echo "<pre>";
  print_r(get_groups("ingja44p"));
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

How do I then take each group and check which groups that each group is a member of, therefore display each and every group that a user is associated with, directly or indirectly ?

Answer (score 1):

The best method to "display each and every group that a user is associated with, directly or indirectly" for Microsoft Active Directory is to use the Extensible Latch Rule that often referred to as [LDAP_MATCHING_RULE_IN_CHAIN](http://ldapwiki.com/wiki/Active%20Directory%20User%20Related%20Searches#section-Active+Directory+User+Related+Searches-AllGroupsAUserIsAMemberOfIncludingNestedGroups).

So a query would look similar to:

```
(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=(CN=UserName,CN=Users,DC=YOURDOMAIN,DC=NET))
```